# CppUnit: How to print failure details immediately

Tags: c++, cppunit

I use the following code to run CppUnit tests:

```
CppUnit::TextTestRunner runner;
CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry &registry = CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry();
runner.addTest(registry.makeTest());
bool result = !SehSafeTestExecutorCPPUnit::Execute(runner);
return result;
```

It prints dots and 'F' but the details on each error are printed afterwards. Is it possible to print details on fails immediately like it's done in gtest?

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you, but if you know gtest, why not using that? We replaced cppunit with gtest 2 years ago. Good choice.

Comment: @TobiasWollgam, thanks) I too prefer gtest but have to deal with a legacy project. Now I working on moving to gtest

Answer (score 0):

You can derive a custom class from [`TestListener`](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/class_test_listener.html), and implement your custom reporting in `endTest()`.  Don't forget you have to add your custom `TestListener` to your [`TestResult`](http://%20http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/class_test_result.html).

If you're only interested in the instant reporting of failures, you can create a custom [`TestResultCollector`](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/class_test_result_collector.html) and overload `addFailure()` with a call to your own output (don't forget to call the parent `addFailure()`.)